# Store timestamp as key in Firebase?

Tags: logging, firebase, time, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to store timestamps as keys in a Firebase database.

My actual use case is to store logs based on timestamps.

So, it's something like:

```
logs: {
 user1: {
  "2016-12-02T06:57:31+00:00":"70",
  "2016-12-02T06:57:32+00:00":"21",
  "2016-12-02T06:57:33+00:00":"26"
 },
 user2: {
  "2016-12-02T06:57:31+00:00":"88",
  "2016-12-02T06:57:32+00:00":"36",
  "2016-12-02T06:57:33+00:00":"45"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, just use the timestamp as a reference to set its value

```
  firebase.database().ref("logs/"+"2016-12-02T06:57:31+00:00").set("70");
```

Comment: It won't be any problem?

Comment: That really depends on how you use it. Personally I'll still go with autogenerated keys and having timestamps as part of the node's metadata. The timestamp key is still a string so I can't see a problem if you'll still continue in using it.

Comment: Using the date/time as a key has the inherent risk of users posting at the same time and thus creating the same key. The built-in `push()` method is also based on the current timestamp, but does not have that potential conflict. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Comment: But I need the timestamp. What do you suggest?

Comment: But, I have a "username" child under logs, so, I guess it might not be a problem. What do you think?

Comment: I agree with the "depends on how you use it argument", but would also have the timestamp as part of the node's data because you can than map your node to a custom object on the client side, whereas if you have the timestamp in the key you can't (directly). So you might need to handle this in a more complex way on the long run. (I actually did this in a project:  having a timestamp as the key seemed more intuitive that time, but regretted it later because of this reason.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can put any string you like as the key in the database (up to a reasonable size limit, I imagine).

For dates, I would recommend simply storing the number of seconds (or milliseconds) since the epoch.  It will be smaller, and easier to convert to various other date representations.  It will also cause the keys to sort chronologically (same as their integer sort order).  See "[orderByKey](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#orderbykey)".  You will also be able to pull ranges of dates with queries using startAt() and endAt().

However, if you prefer your current timestamp format as a key, I don't think it will be a problem.

Comment: Is it not possible to sort when I store the `timestamp` as key? Will the "orderByKey" still work?

Comment: My explanation is all about using a timestamp as a key, and the ability to sort with that value using orderByKey.

Comment: Oh, I mean not the UNIX Epoch. The ISO 8601, like `2016-12-02T06:57:31+00:00`

Comment: It's called a timestamp, isn't it..? Sorry if it's not.

Comment: As I said in my answer, I don't think it's a problem if you use either one, but there are advantages to using the number form.

Comment: Okay. Sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The keys of firebase database are String, then **yes** you can store timestamp as key. If you have any doubts, you can see this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) for more information.

Good programming!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, however, depending on how fast the user inputs information, you might get duplicated timestamps for the same user.

In this case, I'd suggest using [Firebase Push ID's](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) as quoted by @FrankvanPuffelen, which is:

> A push ID contains 120 bits of information. The first 48 bits are a timestamp, which both reduces the chance of collision and allows consecutively created push IDs to sort chronologically. The timestamp is followed by 72 bits of randomness, which ensures that even two people creating push IDs at the exact same millisecond are extremely unlikely to generate identical IDs.