# Saving serverTimestamp in an object within firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm referencing this question ([Store timestamp as key in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927801/store-timestamp-as-key-in-firebase)), and I believe I should be able to store map with an object that contains a key as a timestamp in firebase. However, the code below gives me obj: {[object object]: event}.

Any suggestions as to how I can store a timestamp as a key in a single map field in firebase so I can have an object with key/value pairs that are timestamps with the corresponding event?

```
  let obj = {}
  let ts = serverTimestamp();
  
  obj[ts] = event;

  await setDoc(
    docRef,
    {

      events: obj,
    },
    { merge: true }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use a server-side timestamp in a field name in a Firestore document. If you want to use a timestamp as a field-name, the simplest options is to use a client-side value

---

An more complex alternative (that will get you the server-side timestamp) would be to:

1. first write the timestamp as a **value**,
2. then read the document back with that value,
3. and then use it as a field name.

This is something you could do in your current client, or through a trigger like in Cloud Functions or Cloud Run.